# Getting the SUM in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to display the sum of three campaigns in a visual line graph for the current month. Currently, the JSON results are displaying each campaign daily with the correct results, but three for every day. I can't add the SUM in the original SQL statement because I need the sum of the daily results from the current month, not the total sum for the entire month.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this needs to be done in the `while` loop. I'm still learning PHP and can't think of a solution. I've tried adding a few `if, else if` conditions in the `while` loop looking for the individual campaign and setting the result to a variable which is then added up and used to replace the `$monthlySEMClicksJSON` variable, but to no avail.

How can I accomplish this?

```
    // Current Month JSON
$monthQueryResultJSON = "SELECT * FROM AdWords_Reporting WHERE CampaignID IN('CAMP008', 'CAMP011', 'CAMP044') AND AveragePosition != '0' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) ORDER BY Date ASC";
$monthlyResultJSON = mysql_query($monthQueryResultJSON) or die(mysql_error());

$monthlySEMClicksJSON = '';
$monthlySEMImpressionsJSON = '';
$monthlySEMDateJSON = '';
$printClicksMonthlySEM = '';
$printToolTipMonthlySEM = '';
$printImpressionsMonthlySEM = '';
while($singleRowMonth = mysql_fetch_array($monthlyResultJSON)){
    $monthlySEMClicksJSON = $singleRowMonth['TotalClicks'];
    $monthlySEMImpressionsJSON = $singleRowMonth['TotalImpressions'];
    $monthlySEMDateJSON = $singleRowMonth['Date'];
    $printClicksMonthlySEM .= json_encode($monthlySEMClicksJSON).",";
    $printImpressionsMonthlySEM .= json_encode($monthlySEMImpressionsJSON).",";
    $printToolTipMonthlySEM .= json_encode("<b>Date:</b> " .$monthlySEMDateJSON . "<br /><b>Total Impressions:</b> " . $monthlySEMImpressionsJSON . "<br /><b>Total Clicks:</b> " .$monthlySEMClicksJSON).",";      
}
```

Comment: Your Java background is so obvious... :D

Comment: Am only a beginner with server side language @RaduMurzea. Not sure if this is good or bad...

Comment: Hmmm... I based my assumption on the fact that you use long variable names, which is uncommon in the PHP world. You write them in camel-case too. Never mind, this obviously has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @RaduMurzea, I got ya - right over my head, but thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

format the date in the SQL to month, i.e. `'Ym'` and make an aggregate over this.

```
SELECT 
sum(field1) as sfield1, sum(field2) as sfield2, date_format(date, '%Y%m') as dateaggregate 
FROM AdWords_Reporting WHERE CampaignID IN('CAMP008', 'CAMP011', 'CAMP044') 
AND AveragePosition != '0' AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) 
Group by dateaggregate 
ORDER BY Date ASC"
```

(this is not tested SQL, just a hint!)

Result: aggregated values per month. This can be easily altered to any time frame like year, month, week, quarter etc.

Besides: "date" is a reserved word in SQL and naming column like this is not a good idea.